# How to fix the return type of the last promise in a chain?

Tags: javascript, typescript, promise, es6-promise

I want to return the last promise in a chain as the result of a function. I'm using TypeScript 1.7 and native, ES6 promises.

I tried this, but TS considers the first promise as the return value (the Uint8Array), not the CryptoKey from importKey. I've seen JavaScript examples that make me think the last promise is actually the return value, so maybe TS is just confused?

```
private getKey(): Promise<Uint8Array> {
    return localforage.getItem<Uint8Array>("key")
        .then<Uint8Array>((derivedKeyData) => {
            return crypto.subtle.importKey("raw", derivedKeyData, { name: "AES-GCM" }, false, ["decrypt"]);
        });
}
```

How do I return the inner promise as the result of the function? Or at least convince TS that's what's really happening without making the function's return type "any"?

Comment: I don't know TS so I'll just comment: you immediately return `localForage.getItem` so that is why your type signature must match. To work around this, you'd have to wrap the whole method body with `return new Promise<CryptoKey>(resolve, reject) => ...` and have the `importKey` call the `resolve()` .. something like `importKey(...).then(resolve).catch(reject)`

Comment: @Matt I started down this route, which seemed like it would work, but then I realized my typing mistake as I mentioned below the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a look at your code on http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground and the issue seems to be that the inbuilt resulting type of importKey is 'any'
[image]

Comment: This answer led me to the right answer - the type of the `then` is meant to represent the output type of the next promise, and is also the return type of the function. So the function really is returning the last promise in the chain, I just had my types mised up. E.g. `return localforage.getItem("x").then<CryptoKey>((forageItem)=>{ return crypto.importKey(...); })` This works in my case because even though in the TS definitions importKey returns `any` in my use it's a `CryptoKey`.